# how to get a variable from a module's namespace like you can with exported functions

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-module

I can import my module and access a variable it exports

```
Import-Module -Verbose -Force "MyModule.psm1"
$VarFromModule
```

But I want to reference it from the module namespace like you can with functions:

```
Import-Module -Verbose -Force "MyModule.psm1"
MyModule\FuncFromModule -arg123 abc # this works
MyModule\VarFromModule # doesnt work
MyModule\$VarFromModule # doesnt work
```

Answer (score 0):

An undocumented thing the call operator can do:

```
$m = get-module mymodule
& $m $varfrommodule
```

Comment: dont really like that. I just need a namespace. Is there at least a way to enforce all variables be explicitly imported? its such a mess, I need to make it clear where the vars are coming from im my powershell scripts. and if the answer is to use a class with methods for retrieving them thats way too heavy handed